# Performance of querying partition by between indexed column and date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, partitioning

**Problem:** I am confused as how to take advantage of indexed columns for improved performance or quicker execution time specifically in window functions.

**Situation:** I am ranking transactions based on the order date (oldest to newest).
My first instinct is to ORDER by issue_date of the transaction (in the Partition by clause). But then transaction_id column is indexed and is the table's primary key. Looking at the table's properties, the Identity Increment property is Blank (not sure why but guessing its auto increment). So I am hypothesizing that ordering by transaction_id would yield the same output but drastically improve executing speed.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
 transaction_id
 ,CAST(subscription_id as VARCHAR) as subscription_id 
 ,product_id
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY subscription_id ORDER BY issue_date ASC) AS tx_rank 
FROM table.transactions
```

Should I rater switch the issue_date to transaction_id as such:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY subscription_id ORDER BY transaction_id ASC) AS tx_rank
```

**Note:** This query is taking over 10mns and I want to improve its performance as much as possible.

Comment: What happens when you try?   What do the two execution plans show?

Comment: @Tab Alleman when I run the query by itself, it crashes. this is part of a cte that I combine with other queries. i'm trying to find ways in alleviating the RAM used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely to make much difference.  The `row_number()` can take advantage of an index on the columns being used -- `(subscription_id, issue_date)` or `(subscription_id, transaction_id)`.

I'm not sure if an index would significantly speed things up.  You are selecting the entire table, and that is probably pretty big.

Comment: thank you ! good to know as I had several cte tables with the same logic. why is my question downvoted btw?